# Print a letter on many pages

Tags: c#, silverlight, printing, silverlight-4.0

I have a print button, that must print two documents : 
-A letter written by this person
Secondly, in the second print, I must take care of a possibly multiPage letter. How can I do this?

The letter is inside a textbox, on my page.

Here is my code :

```
void btPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (itmCandidatSelect.LettreMotiv != null || itmCandidatSelect.LettreMotiv != "")
            {
                _lineIndex = 0;
                _documentBodyLines = new List<string>();
                string[] lines = tbLettreMotiv.Text.Split(new char[] { '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                _documentBodyLines.AddRange(lines);

                PrintDocument maLettreMotiv = new PrintDocument();
                //maLettreMotiv.BeginPrint += new EventHandler<BeginPrintEventArgs>(maLettreMotiv_BeginPrint);
                //maLettreMotiv.EndPrint += new EventHandler<EndPrintEventArgs>(maLettreMotiv_EndPrint);
                maLettreMotiv.PrintPage += new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(maLettreMotiv_PrintPage);

                maLettreMotiv.Print("LettreMotivation_" + itmCandidatSelect.NomCandidat + "_" + itmCandidatSelect.PrenomCandidat);

            }
```

}

```
    int _lineIndex;
        List<string> _documentBodyLines;

void maLettreMotiv_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintLettreMotivTemplate page = new PrintLettreMotivTemplate();
            page.SetHeaderAndFooterText("Lettre de motivation", "");
            int numberOfLinesAdded = 0;
            while (_lineIndex < _documentBodyLines.Count)
            {
                page.AddLine(_documentBodyLines[_lineIndex]);
                page.Measure(new Size(e.PrintableArea.Width, double.PositiveInfinity));
                if (page.DesiredSize.Height > e.PrintableArea.Height && numberOfLinesAdded > 1)
                {
                    page.RemoveLastLine();
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    break;
                }
                _lineIndex++;
                numberOfLinesAdded++;

            }
             e.PageVisual = page;
        }
```

My template :

```
<UserControl x:Class="erecrutement_procclass.Views.PrintLettreMotivTemplate"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             Width="815" 
             Height="1024"
             mc:Ignorable="d"    
             d:DesignHeight="300" 
             d:DesignWidth="400">
<Grid x:Name="documentRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="headerTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="bodyTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="footerTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>


 public partial class PrintLettreMotivTemplate : UserControl
    {
        public PrintLettreMotivTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetHeaderAndFooterText(string header, string footer)
        {
            headerTextBlock.Text = header;
            footerTextBlock.Text = footer;
        }


        public void AddLine(string line)
        {
            bodyTextBlock.Inlines.Add(line);
            bodyTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
        }



        public void RemoveLastLine()
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++)
            {
                bodyTextBlock.Inlines.RemoveAt(bodyTextBlock.Inlines.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

But, When it should go over one page, it stopped, and I only have one pages, and a piece of the letter is missing.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: For Multipage Letter refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.71).aspx, monDocument.Print("Fiche_"); and maLettreMotiv.Print("LettreMotivation_"); should be after setting the Template.

Comment: My visual studio can't find assembly System.Drawing . But i use .NET 4, so why i can't find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this. In PrintLettreMotivTemplate.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DelmePrint.PrintLettreMotivTemplate"
             Width="815" 
             Height="1024"
             >
    <Grid x:Name="documentRoot">
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You've set the height of the printable area to 1024. When I stepped through the code,

```
/* DesiredSize always (793, 1024)
   PrintableArea always (793, 1122) */
if (page.DesiredSize.Height > e.PrintableArea.Height)
```

So the code keeps adding lines to the middle section of the page.

To solve the problem, you need to change the Height in PrintLettreMotivTemplate to MinHeight. This way, the letter will overflow when there are too many lines.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DelmePrint.PrintLettreMotivTemplate"
             Width="815" 
             MinHeight="1024"
             >
    <Grid x:Name="documentRoot">
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with below  property;

```
maLettreMotiv.PrintPage += (s, args) =>
            {
                Candidat monCandidat = this.itmCandidatSelect;

                PrintLettreMotivTemplate monTemplatePrint = PrintableAreaLettreMotiv.printTemplateLettreMotiv(monCandidat);
                monTemplatePrint.Width = args.PrintableArea.Width;
                monTemplatePrint.Height = args.PrintableArea.Height;
                args.HasMorePages = true;
                args.PageVisual = monTemplatePrint;
            };
```

Comment: Seems start printing, but one enormous thing : 3 pages of document work became a 200 pages and more (and very heavy document) when i generate a pdf with pdf creator. How is this possible?

Comment: He also repeat the Textbloc with my title in every page. With a 3 or 4 pages in work, i got a 65 pages in pdf creator. Don't understant why. Is my xaml wrongly written?

Comment: It is a terrible behaviour of Silverlight sending huge amount of data to printer. ın your case you might need to calculate the measures specifically. This [video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight4trainingcourse_sl4lob_06_02_multipageprinting.aspx) might be helpful

Comment: Well, ok, i found how print it. Thank you. Now, i found how print the two documents without errors. Thank you.